# Can't import a contract interface in vyper

Tags: contract-development, import, vyper

I need to import a contract interface using the JSON ABI but I get syntax error when trying to import the interface.

I have created the JSON file in remix and named it `IERC1620.json` then I am trying to import the interface like this:

```
import IERC1620.json as fooBar
```

I have tried to remove the `.json` extension but I still get his syntax error:

```
line 1: Unknown interface fooBar import IERC1620.json as fooBar
```

I checked the [documentation](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.10/structure-of-a-contract.html#contract-interfaces) and what I am doing should be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was correct the way I was doing, I just messed up the name of the files and it couldn't import them